# Rewrite index.php to nothing and other.php to other

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to create a simple CMS.
I need the `.htaccess` to rewrite links pointing to `/index.php` to just `/`
while all other `/files.php` to `/files`.

Currently, I am using something like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

This is rewriting `<a href='layout/header.php'>` to `/header` in URL panel, which is good. But navigating back to `/index.php` will result in `/index.php`, which is bad.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This solved my problem**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```